# How to get the future nearest time in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

Suppose we have current time and then add the 60 munites to the current time.

```
Time.now + 1.hours
# => 2022-11-01 16:47:02.965861 +0500
```

after that we get the next half hour like `17:00:00`

I'm able to get the previous half hour time from this code, but unable to find the next half hour time.

```
time = Time.now - 30.minutes
# => 2022-11-01 15:22:59.942013 +0500

Time.at((time.to_time.to_i/1800).round * 1800).to_datetime
# => Tue, 01 Nov 2022 15:00:00 +0500
```

Comment: let me describe my problem again.
I have the current time in hours 18:40 after adding 60 minutes, then this would be 19:40 and then rounded to 20:00.

Comment: FYI, there's an [edit] button you can use to clarify your question.

Comment: It's best to wait at least a couple of hours before selecting an answer, both because another answer may follow that is better than the one you have selected (even though you can change your selection) but also because quick selections can discourage the posting of other answers. Though not in this case, readers sometimes show that the selected answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to map:

- 15:00-15:29 to 17:00
- 15:30-15:59 to 17:30

You could do so with a conditional and [`advance`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-advance) and [`change`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-change):

```
t = Time.current

if t.min < 30
  t.advance(hours: 2).change(min: 0)
else
  t.advance(hours: 1).change(min: 30)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to round up the time to the next 30 min mark i.e if it is between `5:01 and 5:29` you want to make it `5:30`

For that you can just do

```rb
time = Time.now + 1.hours
ceil_minutes = 30.minutes

Time.at((time.to_f / ceil_minutes).ceil * ceil_minutes)
```